# React Native - get value of json depending on dynamic state

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I have a json getting from API and store it into `this.state.data` like :

```
[
  {
    "name": "Primary Category",
    "value": [
      {
        "value": "Fracture",
        "Diagnosis_Code": ["DIAG003"],
        "name": "Primary Category",
        "FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID": 3,
        "FK_Diagnosis_Category_ID": 1
      },
      {
        "value": "Osteoarthritis",
        "Diagnosis_Code": ["DIAG001"],
        "name": "Primary Category",
        "FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID": 1,
        "FK_Diagnosis_Category_ID": 1
      },
      {
        "value": "Osteonecrosis",
        "Diagnosis_Code": ["DIAG002", "DIAG004"],
        "name": "Primary Category",
        "FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID": 2,
        "FK_Diagnosis_Category_ID": 1
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Anatomy",
    "value": [
      {
        "value": "Hip",
        "Diagnosis_Code": ["DIAG001"],
        "name": "Anatomy",
        "FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID": 4,
        "FK_Diagnosis_Category_ID": 2
      },
      {
        "value": "Pelvis",
        "Diagnosis_Code": ["DIAG002", "DIAG003", "DIAG004"],
        "name": "Anatomy",
        "FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID": 6,
        "FK_Diagnosis_Category_ID": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and I have a dynamic state using a function like this:

```
onChangeTextPress(key, value){
  this.state.selected[key] = value
  //another code
}
```

the example of `this.state.selected` is

> [ 'Primary Category': 'Fracture', Anatomy: 'Hip']

I want to get `FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID` json depending on which `this.state.selected[key] and it's value` filled

so depending of `selected` example, I will have a result: `[3, 4]`

because json have a `key` called `name` and the `value` is `Primary Category`, and the `value` of `selected state` `Primary Category` is `Fracture` so I have a value of `FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID` in json, likewise about the `Anatomy: 'Hip'`

I don't know if you all know what I want, but feel free to asking me if you need another information,

hope someone can help me

Comment: is `this.state.select` an object or an array?

Comment: @bennygenel `this.state.selected` is an array with `[ ]` for the first time

Comment: What do you mean by for the first time? `[ 'Primary Category': 'Fracture', Anatomy: 'Hip']` is not a valid syntax. It should be either `[{ 'Primary Category': 'Fracture'}, {Anatomy: 'Hip'}]` or `{ 'Primary Category': 'Fracture', Anatomy: 'Hip'}`.

Comment: but I have those syntax while `console.log(this.state.selected)`, I dunno the real, but if you can solve my issue with your suggest syntax, i can change it later

Comment: Can you please clearify your object and problem? It seems there is an issue wih systax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get use of [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

**Sample 1**

```
// Let's assume you have the below structure
const data = { 'Primary Category': 'Fracture', Anatomy: 'Hip' }

Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => console.log(key))
// Output: 
// Primary Category
// Anatomy
```

So to get the desired value you can use something like below

**Sample 2**

```
// this.state.selected => { 'Primary Category': 'Fracture', Anatomy: 'Hip' }
const keys = Object.keys(this.state.selected);
const result = [];
this.state.data.forEach((d) => {
  if(keys.includes(d.name)) { 
    d.value.forEach((v) => {
      if(v.value === this.state.selected[d.name]) {
        result.push(v['FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID']);
      }
    })
  }
});
console.log(result);
// Output: [3,4]
```

**Sample 3**

```
// this.state.selected => [{ 'Primary Category': 'Fracture'}, {Anatomy: 'Hip' }]
// Since we know there is only one key in every object
const keys = this.state.selected.map((s) => Object.keys(s)[0])
const result = [];
this.state.data.forEach((d) => {
  if(keys.includes(d.name)) { 
    d.value.forEach((v) => {
      if(v.value === this.state.selected[keys.indexOf(d.name)][d.name]) {
        result.push(v['FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID']);
      }
    })
  }
});
console.log(result);
// Output: [3,4]
```

Comment: can you give me an example using array (`[{ 'Primary Category': 'Fracture'}, {Anatomy: 'Hip'}]`) instead of object? or the `sample 2` is an array example?

Comment: @Flix added a third sample

Comment: your nested if is not work, so when i tried to find, I have an undefined while `console.log(this.state.selected[d.name])

Comment: @Flix you were right. Fixed it now but it's a bit complicated solution.

Comment: sure, thanks for the edit sir, now it's work as expected

Answer (score -1):

**You can use this just as**

```
const key = Object.keys(this.state.selected);
const response = [];
this.state.data.forEach((d) => {
if(key.includes(d.tag)) { 
 d.value.forEach((v) => {
  if(v.value === this.state.selected[d.name]) {
    result.push(v['FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID']);
  }
  })
   }
 });
 console.log(result);
```